# JSP hot-swap in Maven glassfish embedded plugin

Tags: maven-2, glassfish-embedded

I am trying to setup embedded glassfish maven plugin and I succeeded, but I can't make jsp files to be hot-swapped.

Here is my config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <instanceRoot>${project.build.directory}</instanceRoot>
        <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
        <app>target/myapp.war</app>
        <port>8080</port>
        <contextRoot>myapp</contextRoot>
        <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Resurrection for further reference.
I managed to do that by deploying an exploded war archive like this.

```
<app>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</app>
```

To generate an exploded war use goal `war:exploded`.

Comment: And for the really brave `<app>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</app>` and `war:inplace`. This means you can edit jsps and see the changes reflected immediately.