# Maven GlassFish embedded plugin. Redeploy after packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-glassfish-plugin

How I can configure auto redeploying after "Package"? 
After running server by command `org.glassfish:maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin:3.1.1:run` I run package `goal` on application (because I need recompile my app after some changes in source code) with following parameters on `maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin`

```
                <execution>
                    <id>undeploy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

But this don't work.

Comment: What does "this don't work" mean? Error message? Or what?

Comment: @khmarbaise, Yes, error msg. In console maven write that this App is not deplyed. After some attempts maven write that port 8080 is busy. But I don't restart server, I only redeploy app.

Comment: Hm. Have you configured the url/ports etc. correctly. Have you tried to deploy/undeploy manually first to see if the EAR/WAR is correct and after that tried it automatically.

Comment: hmm..`deploy/undeploy manually first to see if the EAR/WAR is correct` - where I can find deployed WAR? WHere located embedded glassfish server? I use windows.

Comment: If all you want is hot-deployment during development, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389516/).